# Simple javascript add 1 to a number and output in span html

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

I am trying to build JS which will take a value from a `span` or `div` and add 1000 to the initial value and then output the result in the same span or div the number started in.

There will be about 4 spans to grab values to do at once so I need to loop it

```
<li class="col-md-3 upcoming-events-box-one">
<div>
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
        12 DEC <span class="eventYear">2016</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript to grab the above values from all .eventYear classes on the page + 1 (so in this case 2016 becomes 2017) and then put the new value but into it's correct span it came from

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please put you current js code

Comment: `$('.eventYear').each(function(){
$(this).text(function(){
return +this.textContent + 1;
});
});`

Comment: @Rayon perfect, thanks heaps!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `each()` method is called, it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the object (JQuery).

`this` keyword refers to the current element. Where `text` function can be used to retrieve the text of that element, so simply having a inner callback function to return the update text (increment by 1) would update the value and show

```js
$('.eventYear').each(function() {
  $(this).text(function() {
    return +this.textContent + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<h3>TITLE</h3>
12 DEC <span class="eventYear">2016</span> <br>
12 DEC <span class="eventYear">2015</span> <br>
12 DEC <span class="eventYear">2014</span> <br>
12 DEC <span class="eventYear">2013</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just `$('.eventYear').each(function() {this.textContent = +this.textContent + 1})`.